# How to pass prompt in ansible?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to pass a prompt y in ansible when it executes the below command. When i do manually on server it asks for a prompt. How should i do it with ansible using shell module.Please help with passing the prompt in ansible

```
ubuntu@ip-xx-xxx-xx-xx:~$ tsm pending-changes apply
This operation will perform a server restart. Are you sure you wish to continue?
(y/n):
```

My ansible script:

```
- name: Apply pending configuration changes
  shell: source /etc/profile.d/tableau_server.sh && tsm pending-changes apply -u ubuntu -p '{{ tableau_server_admin_password }}' |
    expect "This operation will perform a server restart. Are you sure you wish to continue?\(y\/n\)"
    send "y\n"
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
  when: inventory_hostname == "xx.xxx.xx.xx"
```

Comment: Why don't you use the `prompt` in Ansible? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html

Comment: Looks like you can pass your command an `--ignore-prompt` flag to suppress the prompt... https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server-linux/en-us/cli_pending-changes.htm#pending-changes-apply

Answer (score 1):

This is what the [ansible expect module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/expect_module.html) is for:

```
- name: Apply pending configuration changes
  expect:
    command: /bin/bash -c "source /etc/profile.d/tableau_server.sh && tsm pending-changes apply -u ubuntu -p '{{ tableau_server_admin_password }}'"
    responses:
      '(y/n):': y
  when: inventory_hostname == "xx.xxx.xx.xx"
```

(Not able to test but something like this is how it should work)